# Running kafka consumer(new Consumer API) forever

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have built a queueing system on `Apache Kafka`. The application will produce messages to particular `Kafka topic` and at the consumer end I have to consume all the records produced to the topic.
I wrote consumer using new Java Consumer Api.
The code looks like

```
  Properties props = new Properties();  
                     props.put("bootstrap.servers", kafkaBrokerIp+":9092");  
                     props.put("group.id",groupId);  
                     props.put("enable.auto.commit", "true");
                     props.put("session.timeout.ms", "30000");
                     props.put("auto.offset.reset", "earliest");
        props.put("key.deserializer","org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
        props.put("value.deserializer","org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
        KafkaConsumer<String, String> consumer = new KafkaConsumer(props);
                     consumer.subscribe(Arrays.asList("consumertest"));  
                     while (true) {  
                         ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = consumer.poll(100);  
                         for (ConsumerRecord<String, String> record : records){  
                             System.out.println("Data recieved : "+record.value());  
                             }  
                     }
```

Here I need to run the consumer forever so that any record pushed into kafka topic by the producer should instantly consumed and processed.
So my Confusion is, is it a right way to use an infinite while loop (like in the sample code) to consume the data ?

Answer (score 2):

While it's ok to have an infinite loop, a slightly more elegant approach can be found in the Kafka consumer [documentation](https://kafka.apache.org/11/javadoc/index.html?org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html) which goes as follows:

```
public class KafkaConsumerRunner implements Runnable {
    private final AtomicBoolean closed = new AtomicBoolean(false);
    private final KafkaConsumer consumer;

    public void run() {
        try {
            consumer.subscribe(Arrays.asList("topic"));
            while (!closed.get()) {
                ConsumerRecords records = consumer.poll(10000);
                // Handle new records
            }
        } catch (WakeupException e) {
            // Ignore exception if closing
            if (!closed.get()) throw e;
        } finally {
           consumer.close();
        }
    }

    // Shutdown hook which can be called from a separate thread
    public void shutdown() {
        closed.set(true);
        consumer.wakeup();
    }
}
```

This allows you to have the option of a graceful shutdown using the hook.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use the infinite loop. Actually, it's not a busy loop. During each poll if data is not available, the call waits for the given period of time.

```
long millisToWait = 100;
consumer.poll(millisToWait);
```

The new-consumer automatically handles the network communication issues. Make sure that, on shutdown the consumer closes gracefully.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, its the right way to use an infinite loop to consume data.

Consumers are usually long-running applications
that continuously poll Kafka for more data. Consumers must keep polling Kafka or they will be considered
dead and the partitions they are consuming will be handed to another
consumer in the group to continue consuming.

poll() returns a list of records. Each record contains the topic and partition the
record came from, the offset of the record within the partition, and the
key and the value of the record. Processing of record is application specific.

In case you exit the loop, always close() the consumer before exiting. This will close the network connections and sockets and will also trigger a rebalance immediately.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me, but you might want to put your inner loop in a try/catch block in case you throw any exceptions. Also consider a periodic reconnect task if you disconnect.